# Recursive Knockout list - setting selected value without jQuery

Tags: jquery, recursion, knockout.js

I tend to regret using jQuery within a Knockout Viewmodel if I'm trying to change the style or visibility of an element. So I'm guessing there's a better way of doing this:

I have some recursive Knockout View Models to display a tree structure of Companies, the managers in those companies and any companies under those managers and on and on (hence the recursive-ness).

How can I set an observable in a child (ManagerViewModel) from within a $root (ApproverViewModel) when I'm creating these objects recursively? Currently I'm doing it with jQuery, and setting the value of a hidden element, but that seems to go against the observable pattern of KO - that makes me think there's a better way of which I'm just unaware.

In the MangerViewModel I'm setting `_self.DefaultApproverClass()` the first time the page loads. Then when the user selects a different Manager I just remove all the classes, find the ID of the newly selected element and apply a CSS class to it.

I'm guessing there's a better, more "Knockout recursion" way of doing this. Any suggestions?

Here's a somewhat slimmed down version of my ViewModels ([the complete version is in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barryman9000/H9V7g/6/))

```
be.ApproverViewModel = function (data) {
    var _self = this;

    _self.UserCompanies = ko.observableArray(
        ko.utils.arrayMap(data.userCompanies, function (item) {
            return new be.CompanyViewModel(item);
        })
    );
    _self.SetSelectedManager = function (data, event) {
        // remove all classes, then add the selected class to the selected element
        $('.selectedApprover').removeClass('selectedApprover');
        $('#' + data.ClientID()).addClass('selectedApprover');
        // set UI elements
        $('#selectedClientID').text(data.ClientID());
        $('#selectedManagerName').text(data.ManagerName());
    };
    _self.GetSelected = function (data, event) {
        console.log($('#selectedClientID').text());
    };
};

be.CompanyViewModel = function (data) {
    var _self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, _self);

    _self.Companies = ko.observableArray(
        ko.utils.arrayMap(data.Companies, function (item) {
            return new be.CompanyViewModel(item);
        })
    );
    _self.Managers = ko.observableArray(
        ko.utils.arrayMap(data.Managers, function (item) {
            return new be.ManagerViewModel(item);
        })
    );
};
be.ManagerViewModel = function (data) {
    var _self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, _self);

    _self.DefaultApproverClass = ko.observable('');
    _self.SubordinateMgrs = ko.observableArray(
        ko.utils.arrayMap(data.SubordinateMgrs, function (item) {
            return new be.ManagerViewModel(item);
        })
    );
    // Styles

    _self.LoadStyleSelected = function () {
        if (_self.IsDefaultApprover()) {
            _self.DefaultApproverClass('selectedApprover');
            $('#selectedManagerName').text(_self.ManagerName());
            $('#selectedClientID').text(_self.ClientID());
        }
    };
    // just call it the first time
    _self.LoadStyleSelected();

};
```

The Markup

```
<div id="CompanyTree">
    <div class="selectedApproverHeader">
        <h4 class="lighter smaller">Currently Selected Approver:
        <br />
            <span id="selectedManagerName"></span>,
            ID: <span id="selectedClientID"></span>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="approver-list-contaier">
        <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'companyElement', foreach: UserCompanies }"></ul>
    </div>
    <script id="companyElement" type="text/html">
        <li class="companyList">
            <h4 class="smaller" data-bind="text: CompanyName"></h4>
            <ul class="managerList" data-bind="template: { name: 'managerElement', foreach: Managers }"></ul>
            <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'companyElement', foreach: Companies }"></ul>
        </li>
    </script>
    <script id="managerElement" type="text/html">
        <li class="managerList">
            <span data-bind="text: ManagerName, attr: { id: ClientID },  css: DefaultApproverClass, click: $root.SetSelectedManager"></span>
            <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'managerElement', foreach: SubordinateMgrs }">
            </ul>
        </li>
    </script>
    <div>
        <button data-bind="click:$root.GetSelected">Click Me</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: any reason you are not making this a custom data-binding?

Comment: @Ben - I was thinking I'd run into the same problem. If you have a suggestion as to how I'd accomplish that, I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop all jQuery code, use ko to control all view presentation, have a look of the updated jsfidder http://jsfiddle.net/H9V7g/9/

To deal with your complex data, there is an init logic to find out initial default manager.

```
be.ApproverViewModel = function (data) {
    var _self = this;
    _self.SelectedManager = ko.observable();

    _self.UserCompanies = ko.observableArray(
    ko.utils.arrayMap(data.userCompanies, function (item) {
        return new be.CompanyViewModel(item);
    }));

    _self.GetSelected = function (data, event) {
        if (_self.SelectedManager()) alert(_self.SelectedManager().ClientID());
    };

    // init default one
    function find_default(companies) {
        var default_manager;
        ko.utils.arrayFirst(companies, function(c) {
            var a_default = ko.utils.arrayFirst(c.Managers(), function(m) {
               return m.IsDefaultApprover(); 
            });

            if (a_default) {
                default_manager = a_default;
                return true;
            } else {
                var deeper_default = find_default(c.Companies());
                if (deeper_default) {
                    default_manager = deeper_default;
                    return true;
                }
            }    
        });
        return default_manager;
    }

    _self.SelectedManager(find_default(_self.UserCompanies()));
};
```

BTW, you can simplify find_default() if you are willing to sacrifize readability.
http://jsfiddle.net/H9V7g/10/

```
// init default one
function find_default(companies) {
    var default_manager;
    ko.utils.arrayFirst(companies, function(c) {
        return default_manager = ko.utils.arrayFirst(c.Managers(), function(m) {
           return m.IsDefaultApprover(); 
        }) || find_default(c.Companies());
    });
    return default_manager;
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you! I was toying with a recursive loop but couldn't figure it out. And thanks for supplying both examples.